# PHP CSV import script isn't replacing SQL data

Tags: php, sql, csv

So I am running this script on my server and need it to replace all of the data in the SQL table with the data in my CSV file:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost"; 
$databasename = "import"; 
$databasetable = "import"; 
$databaseusername="import"; 
$databasepassword = "password"; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile = "test.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
  die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
    $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
  LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

I have added REPLACE INTO TABLE hoping it would replace it however it just keeps stacking on top of the table.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image: Table]

Comment: Why not truncate the table first?

Comment: Replace works when you have unique/primary keys set up . Without a table shema is hard to know what's the problem . Maybe you just have new data in the csv file . Why are you using replace , maybe a truncate table + INSERT would be better if you allways get new data from the csv (unless you need the old data too , don't truncate).

Comment: Thanks guys just done a 4 hour course on MySQL databases ha TRUNCATE does seem to be the way to go, how I can I add that to my script I am unsure however I'll have a play about :)